# Windows 10 custom imaging

Tags: imaging

I am working on designing a new custom Windows 10 image to help make configuring my organization's new computers much more efficient. I have tried cloning only to realize that I am unable to change the computer name. I would like to make the image bootable and to contain programs and licensing information for commonly used software. When using NTLite, I can make the image but when I go to use it, an error message reads "cannot find bootable media", I have double checked to make sure that the option was selected when creating the image. Does anyone have a suggestion as to what would be the best software or practice to use?

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren’t using the tools Microsoft provides for exactly this purpose? Sysprep, imagex, dism, wds, mdt.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into Provisioning Packages. You customize the package, and add it to each Windows 10 install.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/provisioning-packages/provisioning-packages